# how i can check that user is from specific state of usa by getting his location in flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

Actually I want to make my app available only in limited states of US, when user isn't from those specific states he won't  be able to use app.

let me know the best way to achieve this , thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

If you are taking input from user as a pincode then you can validate specific pincode which are available in US. If you are taking user's current location from device, then you can use `geocoder` library. and you can get the pincode from this..

then compare pincode with your specified list.

[geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder)

**Solution 2**

You can compare entered or recived pincode using below regex which allows only US pincodes.

```
(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{9}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)
```